# Windows 8 JavaScript/HTML/CSS App Development - Add .wav Sound Effect to Game

Tags: windows-8

I downloaded the Windows 8 touch game sample from the Windows 8 Dev Center. This sample has a .wav file that is played when the ball hits the corner of the screen. I looked through the code and could not figure out how it worked.

I'm looking for simple directions on playing .wav files. I've imported my short .wav files into my Visual Studio project.

In JavaScript how do I:

1) Import the file in (example: myWavFile = "/sounds/myWavFile.wav")
2) Play the file in my code (example: myWavFile.play();

Answer (score 0):

Place the .wav file in your project - in my example it is in the directory **sounds** that I added.  Then do something like this...

```
var audio;

function playSound(wavfile) {
    audio.setAttribute('src', wavfile);
    audio.play();
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('demoButton').onclick = function () { playSound('sounds/pow.wav');};

    audio = document.createElement('audio');
};
```

You could also move the **onload** function into your WinJS **activated** event.

};